# Bayes rule and application for stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let the process $S_t$ be given by
$$dS_t = S_t(\mu_tdt + \sigma dW_t) $$ for constants $\mu>0,\sigma>0$ and $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion under probability measure $P$.
Let us define a new measure $\frac{dQ}{dP} = exp(-\lambda W_T - 0.5*\lambda^2 T )$ which is simply the Radom-Nikodym derivative for $\lambda=\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$.

Apply Bayes rule and show that $$E^Q[S_T] =  S_0e^{rT} $$

I know how to derive this using Girsanov theorem. That is, we can write $dW_t^Q = dW_t + \lambda dt$ and we have it. But I want to derive this using Bayes rule and computing the expectations. This is how I started
$$E^Q[S_T] = E^P[\frac{dQ}{dP}S_T] = E[e^{-\lambda W_T - 0.5\lambda^2 T }S_te^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)T + \sigma W_T}] $$

but substituting out $\lambda=\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$ in the above expression does not lead to the result. Where did I go wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: @NicholasLP I always do it but forgot this time. Thanks for reminding, I just did it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to evaluate $S$ in $t=0$, that is, $S_0$, otherwise you cannot get rid of the expectation on it and you have to resort to a conditional expectation wrt the sigma algebra in $t$. Moreover, you cannot really use the $T$ index, if you do not start at 0 (you would have to use $(T-t)$).

Then, collect the terms in $W_T$ and apply the moment generating function for a standard normal to those as follows.

- Use $S_0$

$$
E^Q[S_T] = E^P[\frac{dQ}{dP}S_T] = E^P[e^{-\lambda W_T - 0.5\lambda^2 T }S_0e^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)T + \sigma W_T}]
$$

- Collect terms in $T$ and in $W_T$ and rearrange

$$
= S_0E^P[e^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)T - 0.5\lambda^2 T }e^{-\lambda W_T + \sigma W_T}]
$$

$$
= S_0E^P[e^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)T - 0.5\lambda^2 T }e^{-\lambda W_T + \sigma W_T}]
$$

- take out what is known

$$
= S_0e^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)T - 0.5\lambda^2 T }E^P[e^{-\lambda W_T + \sigma W_T}]
$$

- apply the moment generating function of a standard normal variable and simplify

$$
= S_0e^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)T - 0.5\lambda^2 T }e^{0.5(-\lambda + \sigma)^2 T}
$$

$$
= S_0e^{(\mu-0.5\sigma^2 - 0.5\lambda^2 + 0.5\lambda^2 + 0.5\sigma^2 - \lambda\sigma) T}
$$

$$
= S_0e^{(\mu - \lambda\sigma) T} = S_0e^{(\mu - \frac{\mu - r}{\sigma}\sigma) T} = S_oe^{rT}.
$$